# String Operations and Manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I'm building a scraping spider and I would like some help on how to extract the right information out of each response in Python

```
response.css(".print-acta-temp::text").get()
```

'TEMPORADA 2021-2022'

I would like to know how to collect only the 2021-2022. Should I use the str command?

```
response.css(".print-acta-data::text").get()
```

'Data: 14-05-2022,  19:00h'

I need to extract only the date into one variable and the time into another variable.

```
response.css(".print-acta-comp::text").get()
```

' CADET PRIMERA DIVISIÓ - GRUP 2'

I need to collect the data before the first space, the data collected between the 2 spaces and finally the number into another variable.

```
response.css(".print-acta-jornada::text").get()
```

'Jornada 28'

I need to collect the data after the first space.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Should I use the str command?" I don't understand what you think this means. The built-in `str` **function** (not "command") is used to convert other kinds of things to a string. However, it looks like you already have a string.

Comment: There are many separate things you want to do here, each of which is a common task. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We expect **one** question at a time, and it should be something that is not well covered by existing questions. For example, try [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+get+part+of+string), writing some code, and then see if you have a more specific, consistent question about the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you trust the website to produce the data you want exactly followed by 'TEMPORADA ' all the time you can use

```
tu_string = 'TEMPORADA 2021-2022'
nueva_string = tu_string.replace('TEMPORADA ','')
print (nueva_string)
```

like, there's regex and all of that, but you can worry about learning that later, tbh.

> I need to collect the data before the first space, the data collected
> between the 2 spaces and finally the number into another variable.

a simple way to do this is to split

```
teva_string = 'CADET PRIMERA DIVISIÓ - GRUP 2'
teva_lista = teva_string.split(' ')
print (teva_lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any decision on how to parse a string is going to depend on one's assumptions about what form the strings are going to take. In the particular case of 'TEMPORADA 2021-2022', doing `my_string.split(' ')[1]` will get the years. `'Data: 14-05-2022, 19:00h'.split(' ')` will get the list `['Data: 14-05-2022,, '19:00h']`, while `'Data: 14-05-2022, 19:00h'.split('-')` will get `['Data: 14-05-2022', ' 19:00h']`. You can also use datetime libraries or regular expressions, with the latter allowing for more customization if the form of your data varies.